# Relations between supremum, infimum the basis of Banach space and its associated sequence of coefficient functionals

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $E$ be a Banach space with a basis $\{x_n\}$ and let $\{f_n\}$ be the a.s.c.f. Then

The coefficient functionals $\{f_n\}$ associated to the basis $\{x_n\}$ are continuous linear functionals on $E,$ i.e. we have $f_n \in E^*\text{ }(n=1, 2, ...)$. Moreover, there exists a constant M such that
$$ \label{c_fs_are_cts_inequality} 1 \leq \|x_n\|\|f_n\|\leq M (n=1,2,...),$$
and is the unique sequence in $E^*$ that is biorthogonal to $\{x_n\}.$

From that we infer

Corollary

Let $E$ be a Banach space with a basis $\{x_n\}$ and let
$\{f_n\}\subset E^*$ be the associated sequence of coefficient
functionals. Then

a) We have $\displaystyle\inf_{1 \leq n
<\infty}\|x_n\|>0$ if and only if $\displaystyle\sup_{1 \leq n
<\infty}\|f_n\|<\infty.$

b) We have $\displaystyle\sup_{1 \leq n <\infty}\|x_n\|<\infty$ if
and only if $\displaystyle\inf_{1 \leq n <\infty}\|f_n\|>0.$

How can i prove this corollary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't the corollary follow immediately from:

$$\frac {1}{\Vert f_n \Vert} \leq \Vert x_n \Vert \leq \frac{M}{\Vert f_n \Vert}$$

If $\Vert f_n \Vert$ is bounded, then $\frac{1}{\Vert f_n \Vert}$ is bounded above $0$ so $\Vert x_n \Vert$ must also be bounded away from $0$.  Conversely, if $\Vert x_n \Vert$ is bounded away from $0$, then $\frac{M}{\Vert f_n \Vert}$ is likewise bounded away from $0$ so $\Vert f_n \Vert$ can't become arbitrarily large.

In other words, suppose $\inf_n \Vert x_n \Vert=0$.  Then for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$, you can find $k$ such that $\Vert x_k \Vert \lt \varepsilon$, which means $\frac{1}{\Vert f_k \Vert} \lt \varepsilon$, which means that $\Vert f_k \Vert \gt \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$.  Since $\varepsilon$ can be arbitrarily small, that means you can find $k$ such that $\Vert f_k \Vert$ is arbitrarily large, so $\sup \Vert f_n \Vert = \infty$.

The remaining direction of part a is proved similarly, using the other inequality.  If $\inf_n \Vert x_n \Vert \gt 0$, then for some fixed $\varepsilon \gt 0$ it's always the case that $\Vert x_n \Vert \gt \varepsilon$, so $\frac {M}{\Vert f_n \Vert} \gt \varepsilon$ for all $n$ and $\Vert f_n \Vert \lt \frac {M}{\varepsilon}$ for all $n$, which means $\sup_n \Vert f_n \Vert \leq \frac {M}{\varepsilon} \lt \infty$.

A similar proof works for part b.

Comment: Any more details will be appreciated

Comment: i beg you pardon, i don't understand what do you mean at all?

Comment: @Roba I've added more detail.